# Nested Cursor causing performance issue

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, nested, cursor

There are two tables

```
PARENT_OBJECT
  PARENT_ID
  ATTR1
  ...
  ATTRn


CHILD_OBJECT (multiple children for the above Parent)
  CHILD_ID
  PARENT_ID
  ATTR1
  ...
  ATTRn

  CHILD_ID
  PARENT_ID
  ATTR1
  ATTRn
```

NEW_TABLE is a table where we are going to insert rows based on PARENT and CHILD objects

The PL SQL query uses two Cursors nested:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR PARENT_CURSOR IS select * from PARENT_OBJECT;

BEGIN
 FOR PARENT_ROW in PARENT_CURSOR
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE values (PARENT_ID, ATTR1,...,ATTRn);

       OPEN CHILD_CURSOR FOR select * from CHILD_OBJECT where PARENT_ID = PARENT_ROW.PARENT_ID
        LOOP
        FETCH CHILD_CURSOR into CHILD_ROW;
        exit when CHILD_CURSOR%notfound;

        insert into NEW_TABLE values (PARENT_ID, ATTR1,...,ATTRn);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE CHILD_CURSOR
  END LOOP;
END;
```

When the above is run it takes more than a couple of hours to run. 
The PARENT table has about 37000 records and each Parent has an average of 2 objects in the child.

How can this be modified to improve performance?

Comment: You don't need PL/SQL or a loop for this. This can be done with a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

As `@a_horse_with_no_name` said there is no need to have PLSQL block. So you can simply do this in Pure `SQL` as :

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
     VALUES (PARENT_ID, ATTR1,...,ATTRn);
/     
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
   SELECT CO.*
     FROM CHILD_OBJECT CO
          INNER JOIN PARENT_OBJECT PO ON CO.PARENT_ID = PO.PARENT_ID;
Commit;
```

However if you really feel the need of a `PLSQL` then you can use `BULK` operation to insert records like below:

```
-- Assumptions
--1) New table has same columns as of Parent and Child table 
--2) Child and Paraent table have same columns.

DECLARE
   CURSOR REC_CURSOR
   IS
      SELECT * FROM PARENT_OBJECT
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *
        FROM CHILD_OBJECT
             INNER JOIN PARENT_OBJECT
                ON CHILD_OBJECT.PARENT_ID = PARENT_ROW.PARENT_ID;

   TYPE var_rec IS TABLE OF REC_CURSOR%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   v_rec   var_rec;
BEGIN
   OPEN REC_CURSOR;

   LOOP
      FETCH REC_CURSOR BULK COLLECT INTO v_rec LIMIT 100;

      EXIT WHEN (v_rec.COUNT = 0);

      FORALL i IN 1 .. v_rec.COUNT
         INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
              VALUES (v_rec (i));
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE REC_CURSOR;

   COMMIT;
END;
```